# Jquery - How to execute effect when element gets dropped

Tags: jquery, animation, draggable, effect, droppable

I want to execute an effect when the user drops an item. How can I do this? Let's say I want to use the effect "bounce".

```
var drop1 = 1;
var drop2 = 2;
var liit = 3;
var counter = 0;

$('.container').droppable({
    accept: '.item',
    drop: function(event, div) { 

        counter++;

        // here I would like to put a function that 
        // the dropped element bounces up and down before the alert.
        if (counter == hit1) {
            alert("You dropped on item");
        }

        else if (counter == hit2) {
            alert("You dropped another item");
        }
    } 
});
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem now?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your looking for the on drop event.

The documentation can be found at this page.

http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop

```
$( ".item" ).on( "drop", function( event, ui ) {
    alert("You dropped on item");
} );
```